# BorderLayout delay issues

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

After a very long couple of days I have determined that there is a delay when displaying text very quickly in a text area if that text area is in a border layout. My question is, why does the following code take 10-20 times longer to execute using border layout than without (comment out one of the two methods either addWithBorderLayout or addWithoutBorderLayout) AND is there a way to use the border layout without this delay? (The problem exists with or without the SwingUtilities invokeLater() method.)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("JEditPane Test");

        //window to display the plyed back text
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Main Frame");

        //holds some text to be played back
        final JEditorPane editPane1 = new JEditorPane(); 
        final JEditorPane editPane2 = new JEditorPane(); 

        //desktop pane to hold docs
        JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();

        //create an internal frame
        JInternalFrame internalFrame1 = new JInternalFrame("Test Doc 1", true, true, true, true);
        internalFrame1.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(editPane1));
        internalFrame1.setSize(400, 400);
        internalFrame1.setVisible(true);
        internalFrame1.setLocation(0, 0);

        JInternalFrame internalFrame2 = new JInternalFrame("Test Doc 2", true, true, true, true);
        internalFrame2.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(editPane2));
        internalFrame2.setSize(400, 400);
        internalFrame2.setVisible(true);
        internalFrame2.setLocation(400, 0);

        //add it to the desktop
        desktopPane.add(internalFrame1);
        desktopPane.add(internalFrame2);

        //map of editor panes
        final Map < String, JEditorPane > mapOfPanes = new HashMap < String, JEditorPane >();
        mapOfPanes.put("1", editPane1);
        mapOfPanes.put("2", editPane2);

        //COMMENT ONE OF THESE TWO OUT!!!
        addWithBorderLayout(mainFrame, desktopPane);
        //addWithoutBorderLayout(mainFrame, desktopPane);

        //for closing
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //set the size and location of the window
        mainFrame.setSize(800,500);
        mainFrame.setLocation(100, 100);

        //make the window visible
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);


        //create some text to display
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("This is a rather long string of text. ");

        //build up a good amount of text
        for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
        {
            //copy it a few times
            builder.append(builder.toString());
        }

        //get the string
        final String longStringOfText = builder.toString();

        //create a thread to call setText on the editor pane
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                //for gathering stats
                int sum = 0;
                int numberOfCharsToPrintFromString = 0;
                Date prev = new Date();
                Date current = new Date();

                System.out.println("Num Panes: " + mapOfPanes.size());

                //for each pane
                for(JEditorPane pane : mapOfPanes.values())
                {
                    //to help in printing subsections of the big string
                    numberOfCharsToPrintFromString = 0;

                    while(numberOfCharsToPrintFromString < longStringOfText.length())
                    {
                        //wait a short amount of time
                        try{Thread.sleep(1);}catch(Exception e){}

                        //grab sections of the long string
                        String text = longStringOfText.substring(0, numberOfCharsToPrintFromString);

                        //set the text of the pane
                        pane.setText(text);

                        //stats
                        numberOfCharsToPrintFromString++;
                        long diff = current.getTime() - prev.getTime();
                        sum = sum + (int)diff;
                        prev = current;
                        current = new Date();
                    }               
                }

                System.out.println("Average time in between events: " + ((double)sum/(double)numberOfCharsToPrintFromString));                  
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }

    private static void addWithoutBorderLayout(JFrame mainFrame, JDesktopPane desktopPane)
    {
        mainFrame.add(desktopPane);
    }

    private static void addWithBorderLayout(JFrame mainFrame, JDesktopPane desktopPane)
    {
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.add(new Label("Top Panel"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainFrame.add(desktopPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainFrame.add(new Label("Bottom Panel"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OS X 10.5.8 using Java version 1.6, I see a comparable disparity unless I set `apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz` at the beginning of `main()`. Here is a related [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons) that affects font rendering quality rather than execution time.

```
if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac OS X")) {
    System.setProperty("apple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz", "true");
}
```

Comment: Interesting... this solved my problem. I'm still confused why this is true. In general, are there a lot of compatibility issues with OSX/Windows/Linux?

Comment: I can only guess that Apple has optimized for its native graphics layer, Quartz. In my experience, there are few compatibility issue, but VirtualBox is handy for a quick check. In this application, I might have used `JTextArea` for its `append()` method: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html

Comment: More info on OSX quartz for java: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/04-JavaUIToolkits/JavaUIToolkits.html

Answer (score 0):

I use JDK6_17 on XP with an older computer and don't notice the difference you experience. My timings where betweenn 20-22 in both cases.

I then changed the sleep time to 10ms and the timings are remarkably similiar.

For the default layout:

Average time in between events: 31.236842105263158
Average time in between events: 31.236842105263158
Average time in between events: 31.236842105263158

For the Border layout:

Average time in between events: 31.236842105263158
Average time in between events: 31.23766447368421
Average time in between events: 31.236842105263158

In fact I can't believe they are identical in 5 of 6 cases.

By default the content pane of a JFrame does use a BorderLayout. So when you add components to the frame all you need to do is:

```
frame.add(topComponent, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(centerComponent);
frame.add(bottomComponent, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

and the frame will add the components to the content pane at the proper location.

Why are you changing the layout of the frame, instead of the content pane. Normally you would only ever change the layout of the content pane. The root pane of the frame is use to hold the menu bar and the content pane. So maybe you change the default layout manager of the entire frame you are causing some problems?

Comment: I am running java.vm.version=17.1-b03-307 on a macbook pro. With the border layout the last three running times were: 

60.92516447368421  
62.32072368421053  
63.99259868421053  
  
Without:   
4.652960526315789  
4.579769736842105  
4.451480263157895  

I changed the layout manager for the content pane rather than the JFrame and got the same results.